# How to lock a cell for editing in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I lock a cell, to prevent edits to its value for the foreseeable future?

Comment: okay i figured it out, first gotta unprotect the cells you want free to edit by Format Cells...->Cell Protection->Protected (since all cells are protected by default but not functional until next step), THEN you protect the sheet by right clicking the sheet, Protect Sheet... then voila:D

Comment: The correct way to give your solution is to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 6):

From: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Protecting_Cells_from_Changes

1. Select the cells that you want to specify the cell protection options for.
2. Choose **Format - Cells** and click the **Cell Protection** tab.
3. Select the protection options that you want. All options will be applied only after you protect the sheet from the Tools menu - see below.
   Uncheck **Protected** to allow the user to change the currently selected cells.
   Select **Protected** to prevent changes to the contents and the format of a cell.
   Select **Hide formula** to hide and to protect formulas from changes.
   Select **Hide when printing** to hide protected cells in the printed document. The cells are not hidden onscreen.
4. Click **OK**.
5. Apply the protection options.
   To protect the cells from being changed / viewed / printed according to your settings in the **Format - Cells** dialog, choose **Tools - Protect Document - Sheet**.
   To protect the structure of the document, for example the count, names, and order of the sheets, from being changed, choose **Tools - Protect Document - Document**.
6. Optional) Enter a password.
   If you forget your password, you cannot deactivate the protection. If you only want to protect cells from accidental changes, set the sheet protection, but do not enter a password.
7. Click **OK**.

Comment: It COULD be right click -> lock cells, but thats way to easy.

Answer (score 3):

How to protect cells in Libreoffice calc:

First select the cells that you want to be NOT protected.

Then do:

```
> format
> cells
> (uncheck) protected
```

Then do:

```
tools
> protect sheet
> (check everything)
> ok
```

That's it.

If, later on, you want to protect or unprotect cells, then do as follows:

```
tools
> protect sheet (uncheck)
```

Then

```
format
> cells
(change the protection on cells as said above)
```

Finally:

```
tools
> protect sheet
> ok
```